# Display system running clock AIX

Tags: linux, unix, aix

I want to display the running system clock in AIX.
For instance i am able to do so in Ubuntu with

```
watch -n 1 date
```

Tnx

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
while true; do clear; date; sleep 1; done
```

Also, if you want a clock plus system status you can use:

```
topas
```